# laravel dusk:install file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-testing

Trying to install dusk on Laravel like this:

> php7.4 artisan dusk:install

I get this error:

```
Dusk scaffolding installed successfully.
Downloading ChromeDriver binaries...

   ErrorException 

  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
php artisan dusk:install --ssl-no-verify
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me.
Where did you find the --ssl-no-verify because it doesn't seem it is in the laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue related to running this version of PHP on Windows. Upgrading all of PHP's files to v7.4.6 or newer resolves the issue. Specifically, the problem lies with the file libssl-1_1-x64.dll in the base PHP directory. Simply replacing only this file with the updated version will resolve the errors.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/786

Comment: Did you try this: php artisan dusk:install --ssl-no-verify

I saw that dusk/issues but the issue was closed so there was no way to add that comment.